# The HTTP status code is returning 0 for many Links

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code,

```
 var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 for(var i = 0 , max = links.length ; i < max ; i++){
       var refLinks = links[i].href;
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('GET',refLinks, true );
          xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
                  console.log("HTTP Status Code:"+xhr.status);
             }
          xhr.send(null);
}
```

Now in the console I am getting xhr.status is 0 for most of the links while those are not broken links and 200 for only few links. and the website I tried for is http://www.scientificamerican.com/ .

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

**Read your browser's JavaScript console**.

You will see a message along the lines of:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://www.scientificamerican.com/`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access.
>   runner-3.27.4.min.js:1 HTTP Status Code:0

Websites are [not allowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) to get users' browsers (with the user's IP address and cookies) to fetch data from arbitrary websites and make it available to JS. That would be a horrible security problem. Sites can give [explicit permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for other sites to access their data with JS.

Answer (score 0):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.scientificamerican.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource...

But he still exist an method to "bypass" the CORS with a simply PHP script.

Here is the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>

        <!-- Script at the end -->
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            var url = "script.php?url=http://www.scientificamerican.com";

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url, true );
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Do ur stuff here
                if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.send(null);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP :

```
<?php
    // Simple use of file_get_contents function
    function loadHTML($url) {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }

    // Test if we got parameters
    if(count($_GET) > 0) {

        // Test if url param
        if(isset($_GET['url']) && strlen($_GET['url']) > 0) {
            $html = loadHTML($_GET['url']);

            $param = parse_url($_GET['url']);

            $http_domain = "http://".$param['host'];

            $find = array(
                 'src="'
                ,'href="'
            );

            $replace = array(
                 'src="'.$http_domain
                ,'href="'.$http_domain
            );

            // Why use str_replace
            // Example : In $html, we got : <img src="/image/test.png" />
            //
            // We have to write the domain for using this image
            //
            // After : we got : <img src="http://example.com/image/test.png" />
            // We see the image
            //
            // It work for script, link, img, iframe, etc...
            echo str_replace($find, $replace, $html);
        }
    }
?>
```

Hope this will help, you can use this for yours.

Sorry for my english